# ProcessBuilder not executing program correctly

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

I am currently trying to make a litlle handy tool, you see I am a network administrator and my boss told me that he wanted me to monitor the network and block certain sites and ip for some game servers, so for the monitoring part we are going to redirect all traffic on the network to a server where we can monitor the traffic before sending it to the gateway.

For this we are going to use arpspoof in linux and I have finished a solution for the blocking of sites and servers, and what I am going to make is a GUI that makes it easier for me to handle and control these things and when I tried running arpspoof from java using a ProcessBuilder it does not work and I get no output?

It also does not enter the while loop. I can't really think of more to write atm, but if I can think of more I will update this thread.

My code:

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("running arpspoof...");
                Process prb = new ProcessBuilder("gksudo", "arpspoof", "-i", "wlan0", Gateway).start();
                InputStream is = prb.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Output: " + line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never used gksudo, but I googled it and it says it's a GUI version of sudo.  I'm guessing that you just launched a GUI app which does not write anything to stdout and which does not return.  If so, then the code is doing what I would expect.  It is blocking until the process writes a line of text that it can read - which never occurs so it blocks indefinitely.

First test your ProcessBuilder code using a trivial command like "echo" to make sure your Java code is working as expected. Then work your way back.  Try running your program as root so you don't need the sudo argument and see if that works.  Then finally try to run it using sudo instead of gksudo.

Answer (score 0):

I think @user is on the right track, but there are a couple of other possible explanations.

1. The gksudo command could be asking for a password.  I'm not sure where it would ask, but there's a good chance that it won't be the "stdout" stream of the "gksudo" process.
2. If "gksudo" or the command that you are "gksudo"-ing fails to launch, there is a good chance that it will write an error message to its "stderr" stream.  But you are not reading "stderr".

To help diagnose this, you need to try the following:

- Look in the log file that for "sudo" - it is "/var/log/secure" on my box.
- Use "ps -efl" (or similar) to see what processes exist while your application is blocked waiting for output.  (If that is happening ...)
- Look to see if "gksudo" is prompting for a password in an unexpected place.
- Try **temporarily** tweaking the "sudoers" file to allow the "arpspoof" command to be "sudo"-ed without a password.